# Best way to loop through .csv file that has two columns and duplicate entries in column 1?

Tags: python, mysql, csv, sqlite

What I'd like to do is loop through my csv file, and then insert that data into my SQL database.  Currently I have this working, except that it only stores one of the values in column 2 instead of all values.  Here is a sample of my .csv file:

```
chad,tall
mike,short
billy,skinny
billy,bald
billy,tall
sarah,tall
sarah,blonde
george,tall
george,bald
steve, short
```

What I'd like to do is, loop through each row, append column 2 and include the additional values if column1 already exists.  Here is my current for loop:

```
# Iterate through the CSV reader, inserting values into the database
for row in creader:
    to_db = [unicode(row[1], "utf8"), unicode(row[0], "utf8")]
    cursor.execute("UPDATE 'people' SET 'description'= ? WHERE name= ?", to_db)
```

This works, except it only stores one value per key.  For example, the database looks like:

```
chad,tall
mike,short
billy,tall
sarah,blonde
george,bald
steve, short
```

What I'm hoping to have is something like:

```
chad,tall
mike,short
billy,skinny,bald,tall
sarah,tall,blonde
george,tall,bald
steve, short
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It looks like the first column of text (`chad`, `mike`, etc.) is a column in your database (possibly `name`, based on your query). If that's the case, how do you intend for something like `billy`'s `skinny,bald,tall` to be stored? As a string joined together with commas? Each value as a separate column (in which case how do you know how many columns your table should have)? As entries in a separate "attributes" table?

Comment: And to add to @Chris is name your primary key?

Comment: @Chris In my real app these are defined values that won't change (the names that is).  I just generalized them here for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I undersand you correctly, the first column is your name, and the second is a description, that may contain commas. If that's the case, then:

```
val_dict = {}

for row in creader:
    try:
        value = val_dict[row[0]]
        value += row[1] + ","
    except KeyError:
        value = row[1] + ","
    val_dict[row[0]] = value


for row in val_dict.items():
    to_db = [unicode(row[1][:-1], "utf8"), unicode(row[0], "utf8")]
    cursor.execute("UPDATE 'people' SET 'description'= ? WHERE name= ?", to_db)
```

Comment: OP want's to merge several lines with same name. Not multiple descriptions on one line.

Comment: @Remi - This did the trick!  Thank you so much!  Now to get a loop going in jinja2.  Thanks again!